# Unable to use custom Ansible configuration file in Packer

Tags: docker, ansible, packer

I am trying to build a Docker image with Packer and use Ansible to provision said image. I would like to use custom Ansible plugins that will be defined in the configuration file but cannot seem to get Packer to properly target the configuration file. I have tried placing the path to the configuration file in `ansible_env_vars` and have also tried to use the `extra_arguments` block to also point to the configuration file. I would also like to note that the Packer build will still build the Docker image regardless if it can properly locate the custom configuration file or not.

Below is an example of what my `Ansible Provisioner` block looks like, my file structure, as well as the Packer build output logs. Any advice on would be much appreciated.

## Packer Block

```
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "ansible",
            "playbook_file": "src/playbook.yml",
            "ansible_env_vars": "src/ansible.cfg",
            "extra_arguments": [
                "-vvv",
                "--extra-vars", 
                "'variable={{ user `variable` }} ..... '" 
            ]
        }
    ],
```

## Packer Build Output

```
    docker: ansible-playbook 2.9.2
    docker:   config file = None
    docker:   configured module search path = ['/Users/andrewgonzalez/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
    docker:   ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
    docker:   executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
```

## File Structure

Keep in mind, I have a Makefile, that will build the Docker image and that lives in my Packer directory. I also have a Makefile in the root directory that will call the Makefile in the Packer directory to execute the build.

```
$ tree -d -L 2
.
├── packer
│   ├── log
│   └── src
├── packerenv
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   └── lib
└── test
```

Comment: So of that output, I don't see any error message -- or is your question why there are only 5 lines of output from `packer build`?

Comment: My question is how to properly set an ansible config file. I placed a portion of the output to illustrate that packer is not properly setting the config file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Ansible (remote) provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html) for Packer, the block should be:

```
"provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "ansible",
        "playbook_file": "src/playbook.yml",
        "ansible_env_vars": [ 
          "ANSIBLE_CONFIG=src/ansible.cfg"
        ],
        "extra_arguments": [
            "-vvv",
            "--extra-vars", 
            "'variable={{ user `variable` }} ..... '" 
        ]
    }
],
```

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake: `ANSIBLE_CONFIG`, I don't know how I overlooked that